# calculate pixel temperature from a 3 channel thermal image

Tags: python, image-processing, computer-vision, physics

Given a 3 channel thermal image in the form of a numpy array, how would one approach calculating pixel-level temperatures corresponding to the image?

My end goal would be to process an image like this:

[image]

For temperatures corresponding to each pixel, and then mask out a specific region and calculate the average temperature of that region.

In terms of retrieval of the images, I simply connect to a thermal imaging camera (Lepton 2.5) via OpenCV and extract frames for further processing.

The basic code:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)

# Capture frame
ret, frame = cap.read()

# TODO
# get a temperature corresponding for each image pixel
temperature_matrix = calculate_temp(frame)
```

Comment: Is there relevant information in the camera's manual?

Comment: use the measurement values from the camera, not the psdeudo color representation. refer to the camera manual. http://xyproblem.info

Comment: ***if*** you ***have to*** deal with colormapped data, it's [possible](https://gist.github.com/crackwitz/ccd54145bec1297ccdd4a0c8f4971deb) to undo the colormap by calculating the nearest-neighbor map color (and its index in the map) for each pixel. -- don't ever even think of doing that if there's _any_ way at all to get the original data, before colormapping.